# Center an image in actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I want to center an image on my action bar. So here it goes...

Here's my **actionbar_about.xml** file. In this xml file is the image located

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/about_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_about" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is where I will overlay or inflate that xml file. 
**AboutUs.java**. This ain't mainactivity.java that's why I'm using **getActivity()**

```
@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ActionBar
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_about, null);
    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.about_actionbar);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_about));

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

THANKS GUYS! :)

Comment: did you tried android:gravity = "center" ?

Comment: Yes, i had tried it. No luck

Comment: did you tried android:layout_centerInParent="true" ? or set 
android:layout_gravity="center" in relativelayout it will work

Comment: Also tried. Still not working. :|

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center" in relativelayout it will work

Comment: Tried it Darkie, but still no luck. In graphical layout, it is in center, but when I run it on emulator it is not. Its beside the drawer icon.

Comment: but your provided code is running ok on my machine ... did you tried using linear layout instead of relative ?

Comment: My code is running but the image that i want to be on the center isn't at the center. Yup, also tried linear.

Comment: Try to remove the "android:orientation = horizontal" from RelativeLayout

Comment: Hi Lucas, I did remove it but still not working. :/

Comment: I SOLVED IT! :D I just replaced android:layout_width="30dp" to android:layout_width="match_parent" :)))

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearanceRegular.FontPath"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gridItemImg"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/box" android:padding="1.5dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gridItemTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridItemImg"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```